# Why does toggling the Visibility of my Form disable my KeyDown event?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, panel, visible

I am creating a grid of `Panels` at runtime and it is very ugly when it resizes due to being created by a loop. In order to "hide" this operation, I have called

`this.Visible = false;`

before my loop and

`this.Visible = true;`

after my loop.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++)
            {
                _panel = new Panel();
                _panel.Location = new Point((i * _panel.Size.Width) + ((i + 1) * _border), (j * _panel.Size.Height) + ((j + 1) * _border));                    
                this.Controls.Add(_panel);
            }
        }
```

The above code works GREAT however it only works once.
After I toggle the visibility of my form, the `KeyDown` event no longer happens with I press a key.

Any ideas?

Comment: setting `Visible` to `false` causes the form to lose focus. Are you sure that the form regains the focus when you make it visible again? It might also be that one of the controls on your form is getting the `KeyDown` events.

Comment: can you confirm this is about Windows Forms? (There's a tag for that)

Comment: @fretje He is definitely referring to WinForms. Re-tagged it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never change visibility for update operations. Rather use:

```
this.SuspendLayout();

// Do all the resizing here.

this.ResumeLayout();
```

Answer (score -1):

`this.Visible` is a server side call which prevents the html control and all of the contents of that control to not be rendered to the client. You might try changing the style to `style="display:none;` so that whatever is inside that 'panel' can be re streamed to the client.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about Windows Forms.

Comment: whoops...in the immortal words of Rosanne Rosannadanna _Nevermind_